# Python3 - Return CSV with row-level errors for missing data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

New to Python. I'm importing a CSV, then if any data is missing I need to return a CSV with an additional column to indicate which rows are missing data. Colleague suggested that I import CSV into a dataframe, then create a new dataframe with a "Comments" column, fill it with a comment on the intended rows, and append it to the original dataframe. I'm stuck at the step of filling my new dataframe, "dferr", with the correct number of rows that would match up to "dfinput".

Have Googled, "pandas csv return error column where data is missing", but haven't found anything related to creating a new CSV that marks bad rows. I don't even know if the proposed way is the best way to go about this.

```
import pandas as pd

dfinput = None
try:
    dfinput = pd.read_csv(r"C:\file.csv")
except:
    print("Uh oh!")

if dfinput is None:
    print("Ack!")
    quit(10)

dfinput.reset_index(level=None, drop=False, inplace=True, col_level=0, 
col_fill='')

dferr = pd.DataFrame(columns=['comment'])
print("Empty DataFrame", dferr, sep='\n')
```

Expected results: "dferr" would have an index column with number of rows equal to "dfinput", and comments on the correct rows where "dfinput" has missing values.

Actual results: "dferr" is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding of 'missing data' here would be null values. It seems that for every row, you want the names of null fields.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],
                   [4,None,6],
                   [None,8,None]],
                  columns=['foo','bar','baz'])
# Create a dataframe of True/False, True where a criterion is met
# (in this case, a null value)
nulls = df.isnull()

# Iterate through every row of *nulls*,
# and extract the column names where the value is True by boolean indexing
colnames = nulls.columns
null_labels = nulls.apply(lambda s:colnames[s], axis=1)

# Now you have a pd.Series where every entry is an array
# (technically, a pd.Index object)
# Pandas arrays have a vectorized .str.join method:
df['nullcols'] = null_labels.str.join(', ')
```

The `.apply()` method in pandas can sometimes be a bottleneck in your code; there are ways to avoid using this, but here it seemed to be the simplest solution I could think of.

EDIT: Here's an alternate one-liner (instead of using `.apply`) that might cut down computation time slightly:

```
import numpy as np
df['nullcols'] = [colnames[x] for x in nulls.values]
```

This might be even faster (a bit more work is required):

```
np.where(df.isnull(),df.columns,'')
```